# Have jQuery return text rather than HTMLScriptElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a script that counts how many external scripts I have on my site.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $tags = $("script[src*='http']");
    $.each($tags, function(index, value) { console.log("INDEX: " + index + " VALUE: " + value ); });
});
```

Index is working as intented, but the value that is printed to the console is `[object HTMLScriptElement]`. How can I modify my script to print the value for src attribute?

I already tried these two changes:

1. From `$("script[src*='http']")` to `$("script[src*='http']").attr('src')`
2. From `value` to `value.toString()`

Answer (score 2):

use `$(value).attr("src")` or `value.src` to get `src` attribute of script tag, change to:

```
...
$.each($tags, function(index, value) { 
    console.log("INDEX: " + index + " VALUE: " + $(value).attr("src") ); 
    //OR
    console.log("INDEX: " + index + " VALUE: " + value.src ); 
});
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $tags = $("script[src*='http']");
    $.each($tags, function (index, value) {
       console.log("INDEX: " + index + " VALUE: " + $(value).attr("src") );
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Bh6Vz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$tags = $("script[src]");
$.each($tags, function(index, value) { console.log("INDEX: " + index + " VALUE: " + value  ); });
});
```